# R shiny error: Error in eval

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where it is possible to filter for manufacturer. However it gives me the error that objects are not found.

I should be able to select cyl and displ. And then type in audi so that the plot only show the points which are audi.

Here is the server code.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

function(input, output) {
dataset<-reactive({mpg})
dataset1<-reactive({
  x<-input$x
  y<-input$y
  data<-dataset 
   if (!is.null(input$z) && input$z != "") {
     z <- paste0("%", input$z, "%")
     data <- data + filter(manufacturer %like% z)
   }
 })

output$plot <- renderPlot({

  p <- ggplot(dataset1(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y))+geom_point()

print(p)

   }, height=700)

}
```

And the ui code
**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- mpg

fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Manufacturer"),

   sidebarPanel(


    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[3]]),
    textInput('z','manufacturer name contains')
 ),

 mainPanel(
  plotOutput('plot')
 )
)
```

This is the error i'm receiving: *Warning: Error in eval: object 'manufacturer' not found*

Anyone able to help out? Thanks!

Comment: `reactive` functions should return a value - e.g. the last line of `dataset1` should be `data` or `return(data)`, and `output$plot` should probably end with `p` or `return(p)`, or possibly `print(p)`. I'm not sure this line is valid: `data <- data + filter(manufacturer %like% z)`. Did you mean `data <- data %>% filter(manufacturer %like% z)`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did mean %>%, good call! As you can see there already is a print(p) in my code. I did add the return(data) at the end of the line. I now get this response: Error in : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive

Comment: This - `data<-dataset` - should be `data <- dataset()`, since `dataset` is a function.

Comment: Awesome that worked! Still having trouble finding the function though: Error in reactive dataset1: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You probably forgot to `library(dplyr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `server.R` with the following code I think you will get what you were looking for.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

library(dplyr)


function(input, output) {
    dataset <- mpg

    dataset1<-reactive({

        data<-dataset 

        if (!is.null(input$z) && input$z != "") {
            data <- filter(data, manufacturer == input$z)
        } 
        data
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

       ggplot(dataset1(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y))+geom_point()

    }, height=700) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! As a follow up. Is it also possible to write the filter in such a way that I can see the data for both audi and chrysler for example?

Comment: The filter should work the way it is written. You would have to change your `textInput` in your UI for something like `selectizeInput('z','manufacturers', choices = levels(dataset$manufacturer), multiple = TRUE)`
That should do the trick.